# Is there way to get value of CDATA and convert in json or array format in php?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, cdata

Here is what it looks like after getting value from CDATA via simplexmlelement

```
$data = "{customertype=New, Telephone=09832354544, CITY=Henfield, LASTNAME=C, TicketNo=123456, FIRSTNAME=Alex, Id=10001273, testfield=123456, COMPANY=Camp1}"
```

I tried looking into solutions in google but i am not able to find one which would convert this set of strings to array.

I want this data to convert into array something like this

```
["customertype"] = ["New"]
["Telephone"] = ["09832354544"]
```

so and so forth or something similar as how array looks like.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Given your data string format, you may do as follows: 
First of all, remove the brackets `{ }`  
Then explode the string using the `,` delimiter. 
Now, you have array of strings containing for example `customertype=New`. 
Next is the tricky part, the result string looks like a query, so we're gonna use
[parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to make an associative array:

The result will be something similar to this:

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "customertype" => "New"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "Telephone" => "09832354544"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "CITY" => "Henfield"
  ]
```

And here's the code:

```php
    $data = "{customertype=New, Telephone=09832354544, CITY=Henfield, LASTNAME=C, TicketNo=123456, FIRSTNAME=Alex, Id=10001273, testfield=123456, COMPANY=Camp1}";

    $rippedData = str_replace(["{", "}"],"", $data);

    $singleData= explode(",", $rippedData);

    $finalArray = [];
    foreach($singleData as $string){
        parse_str($string, $output);
        $finalArray[] = $output;
    }
```

Comment: thank you this works. I don't have enough reputation to like this comment but i really appreciate for you help

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "{customertype=New, Telephone=09832354544, CITY=Henfield, LASTNAME=C, TicketNo=123456, FIRSTNAME=Alex, Id=10001273, testfield=123456, COMPANY=Camp1}";

$stripped = str_replace(['{','}'], '', $data);
$explode = explode(', ', $stripped);

$output = [];

foreach ($explode as $value) {
    $inner_explode = explode('=', $value);
    $output[$inner_explode[0]] = $inner_explode[1];
}

var_dump($output);
```

Results in

```
array(9) {
    ["customertype"]=>
    string(3) "New"
    ["Telephone"]=>
    string(11) "09832354544"
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(8) "Henfield"
    ["LASTNAME"]=>
    string(1) "C"
    ["TicketNo"]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    ["FIRSTNAME"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
    ["Id"]=>
    string(8) "10001273"
    ["testfield"]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    ["COMPANY"]=>
    string(5) "Camp1"
  }
```

Comment: thank you this works. I don't have enough reputation to like this comment but i really appreciate for you help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though there's probably a better/cleaner way to code this.

```
$data = "{customertype=New, Telephone=09832354544, CITY=Henfield, LASTNAME=C, TicketNo=123456, FIRSTNAME=Alex, Id=10001273, testfield=123456, COMPANY=Camp1}";

// Replace squiggles
$replace_this = array("{","}");
$replace_data = str_replace($replace_this,"",$data);

// Explode and create array
$data_array = explode(',',$replace_data);

// Loop through the data_array
foreach($data_array as $value) {
    // Explode the value on the equal sign
    $explode_again = explode('=', $value);

    // Create new array with correct indexes and values
    $CDTA[trim($explode_again[0])] = $explode_again[1];
}
echo '<pre>' . var_export($CDTA, true) . '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
array (
  'customertype' => 'New',
  'Telephone' => '09832354544',
  'CITY' => 'Henfield',
  'LASTNAME' => 'C',
  'TicketNo' => '123456',
  'FIRSTNAME' => 'Alex',
  'Id' => '10001273',
  'testfield' => '123456',
  'COMPANY' => 'Camp1',
)
```

Comment: thank you this works. I don't have enough reputation to like this comment but i really appreciate for you help